# json output convert to other format

Tags: json, linux, awk, text-processing

I have the following output from a script

```
{"emeter":{"get_realtime":{"current":0.501730,"voltage":240.819788,"power":70.455025,"total":1.798000,"err_code":0}}}
```

I need to convert it to this format for prometheus exporter collector:

```
current 0.53
voltage 234
power 84.04
total 0.92
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Why did the voltage change from 240.82 in the input to 234 in the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Comment: the voltage changed because the readings were taken at different times, it is by default like 240.23423 but i need it displayed as 240

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the inner object - consider `my_obj` is your object after parsing your JSON
2. Get your objects' keys as an array of string with `Object.keys()`
3. Ignore "err_code" with `filter` method of `Array`
4. I used console log to log the output - no idea how you wanted it but i guess you can easily figure it out now

```js
var my_obj = {
  "emeter": {
    "get_realtime": {
      "current": 0.501730,
      "voltage": 240.819788,
      "power": 70.455025,
      "total": 1.798000,
      "err_code": 0
    }
  }
}
var inner = my_obj.emeter.get_realtime;
var innerKeys = Object.keys(inner);
innerKeys.filter(k => k !== "err_code")
  .forEach(k => console.log(k, inner[k]));
```

Comment: The snippet runs ok but i have no idea what language is that in, can I do something like this in bash?